# Trying to make an algorithm to warp a grid of pixels

Tags: math, glsl

I started making shaders using GLSL, and wanted to make an algorithm that makes a grid warped in a specific way. Let me explain:

Inside my canvas is a grid with a fixed number of squares in it. I want to make a vector2 "warpXY" which will make the squares near that position bigger, but also modifies the others squares, so they all fit in the canvas. Of course they can be rectangles and not squares at this point.

Here is an example of what I want if it's a curve (the black line is y=0):

[image: The black line is y=0]

There is no problem if it's not GLSL code or if it's only for one axis; I just want to understand how to make that sort of algorithm.

Comment: This very interesting question about 2d transformations has been closed and marked as a duplicate of a question about a 1d function which doesn't even have an answer?! I'm voting to reopen.

Comment: Hey, the other topic is from me, and it's a duplicate in a way. Since this post, i have a clearer idea of what i want and the other post is just this one but less vague.